# Firebase: Querying a list of data created with push()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have Firebase Database that looks like this:

```
{
  "lists" : {
    "-KZh-vvPcPGVqC22k2Bo" : {
      "dateCreated" : "2016-12-23",
      "listDescription" : "My Christmas Wish List for 2016",
      "listTitle" : "William's Christmas List",
      "user" : "ztGAx7eplGeZgdjqnegrtbfuyUy2"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "8pJJuscerZRGdwGGImnWlCKSEed2" : {
      "email" : "example@example.com",
      "name" : "Alyson"
    },
    "ztGAx7eplGeZgdjqnegrtbfuyUy2" : {
      "email" : "example@example.com",
      "name" : "William"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to only return the lists objects where the user field equals the UID of the logged in user. That way the logged in user gets all his lists. But I am having trouble querying the data that is in lists because of the unique key that is generated by push() which I use to append to lists whenever a user creates a new list object. How do I go about querying lists so that I get only the lists that match the UID of the signed in user? I have this so far

```
package com.fanciestw.listpro;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class allList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference mList = mDatabase.getReference().child("lists");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_list);
        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth){
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user != null) {
                    Log.d("User Activity", "User Signed In");
                } else {
                    Log.d("User Activity", "User Signed Out");
                    signout(getCurrentFocus());
                }
            }
        };
        mList.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                List newList = dataSnapshot.getValue(List.class);
                Log.d("List Returned", newList.listTitle + " " + newList.listDescription);
                updateList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                updateList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("allList Activity", "onStart");
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("allList Activity", "onStop");
        if(mAuthStateListener != null) mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    public void addNewList(View view){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Add New List");

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_list_form, null);

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String title = ((EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.add_list_title)).getText().toString();
                String desc = ((EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.add_list_desc)).getText().toString();

                Log.d("New List Details", title + ", " + desc);
                //TODO::Store created list with title and desc in database
                List newList = new List(title, desc, mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                String newListID = mList.push().getKey();
                mList.child(newListID).setValue(newList);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    public void updateList(){
        //Want to get lists where lists.user == firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().UID();
    }

    public void signout(View view){
        mAuth.signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also replace the picture of your JSON tree with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: If you want to search the 'lists' table by user id (where each list is unique to a user) you might want to restructure your table for better query capabilities.  Try might want to try using 'user-id' as the key to each list. That way you can use Firebase's query commands like 'equalTo' to make a fast query. Read about [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Declare**

```
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
    private String userId = null;
```

**Initialize**

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userId = mCurrentUser.getUid().toString();
    String UIDstring = (String) dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue();
```

**Determine**

```
if (userId.equals(UIDstring)) {
       //true
    } else {
      // false
   }
```

Comment: Thank you I totally over looked dataSnapshot.

Comment: Is it possible to capture the id as a wildcard in the URL?